# Android getting a method value inside MainActivity from another activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I try to keep this as simple as possible. I have a SQLite database that containt the following method that return all the names inside a table:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllPlacesNames() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select placeName FROM " + DataTableName,null);
        ArrayList<String> companyNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(result.moveToNext()) {
            String places = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("placeName"));
            companyNames.add(places);
        }
        return companyNames;
    }
```

I have a MainActivity.java inside which I get and return the String array of names by calling the method `getAllPlacesNames()` from DataBaseHelper:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllPlacesNamesMain() {

        return summerJobDB.getAllPlacesNames();
    }
```

Now my Problem. I'm trying to create a custom adapter for list view inorder to display the names. But I do not know how to get the return value of `getAllPlacesNamesMain()` from my adapter file StringArrayAdapter.java and convert it into an array So I can use it inside my constructor. Here is what I have so far:

```
public class StringArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context ctxt;
    LayoutInflater myInflator;
    DataBaseHelper summerJobDB;
    public ArrayList<String> getAllPlacesNamesMain() {return summerJobDB.getAllPlacesNames();}
    String[] places = new String [getAllPlacesNamesMain().size()];
    // convert places to Array
    places = getAllPlacesNamesMain().toArray(places);


    public StringArrayAdapter(String [] arr, Context c) {
        // here I need to set places to arr

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // create a cell to be displayed inside listview (a view)
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: you can use CursorAdapter which is designed to connect to database and avoid so much extra works

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class StringArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context ctxt;
    LayoutInflater myInflator;
    DataBaseHelper mSummerJobDB;
    private ArrayList<String> mAllPlacesNames;

    public StringArrayAdapter(DataBaseHelper summerJobDB, Context c) {
        // here I need to set places to arr
       this.ctxt = c;
       this.mSummerJobDB = summerJobDB;
       mAllPlacesNames = summerJobDB.getAllPlacesNames();

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mAllPlacesNames.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mAllPlacesNames.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // create a cell to be displayed inside listview (a view)
        return null;
    }
}
```

and on your MainActivity, you create the adapter providing a reference to the DatabaseHelper.